# How to set CAShapeLayer mask on the UILabel in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I need to adjust the mask in the UILable for the animation, but this layer.mask method does not run

```
class FirstView: UIView {

    var showAbout: UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        ...
        return label
    }

    var showAboutMask: CAShapeLayer {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        ...
        return layer
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        showAbout.layer.mask = showAboutMask
        addSubview(showAbout) 
    }

}
```

The label is shown but the mask layer does not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are modifying once instance of `showAbout` and then adding another instance as a subview. This happens because `showAbout` is a ["computed property"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259). Computed properties don't actually store a value, instead they *compute* the value each time it's called (like a function).

> You can verify this behavior by setting a breakpoint in the body of `showAbout` and note that it gets called twice.

Because of this, in `initializeViews` when you call

```
showAbout.layer.mask = showAboutMask
```

you compute one `UILabel` instance and modify the mask of its layer. Then, when you call

```
addSubview(showAbout)
```

you compute *another* `UILabel` instance (without the layer mask) and add it as a subview.

Computed properties have their use cases but here you probably want to store the `UILabel` instance. One way of doing this would be to lazily assign it the value of computing a closure, similar to how `showAboutMask` is assigned:

```
lazy var showAbout: UILabel = {
    // same label creation as before
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of initializing the label, the mask should be specified

```
var showAbout: UILabel {
        ....
        label.layer.mask = showAboutMask
        return label
}
```